# Horizontally Align Y Labels of Two Y Axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, alignment, axes

I am trying to create a dual axis plot with y labels on the top of the axis on the same height

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(data_left.index, data_left, label='Preis')
ax.set_ylabel('Preis', fontsize=label_size, rotation=0)
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(0, 1.01)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(data_right.index, data_right, label='KGV')
ax2.set_ylabel('KGV', fontsize=label_size, rotation=0)
ax2.yaxis.set_label_coords(1, 1.01)
```

So I manually set the y label coords height to 1.01 for both axis but they are created in completely different places.

[image]

Of course I could play around with the values until I find a matching position, but I want to use this code for different data and have the labels automatically put to the right place.

- Why are those labels on completely different y coordinates?
- How do I align their y position, so that the alignment works for any dataset and label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as you intended (rotation_mode=anchor + verticalalignment=baseline)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(data_left.index, data_left, label='Preis')
ax.set_ylabel('Preis', fontsize=20, rotation=0, rotation_mode="anchor", verticalalignment='baseline')
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(0, 1.01)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(data_right.index, data_right, label='KGV')
ax2.set_ylabel('KGV', fontsize=20, rotation=0, rotation_mode="anchor", verticalalignment='baseline')
ax2.yaxis.set_label_coords(1, 1.01)
```

The issue was the pivot not being at the center of the text but on the yaxis

[image: before rotation]

[image: after rotation]

Comment: Thanky that is exactly what I was looking for and it also makes perfectly sense!